# Listbox com seleção sincronizada

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Ola! Eu estou estudando sobre Tkinter e gostaria de saber se tem como fazer com que as duas Listbox que eu crie, tenha seleção sincronizadas, e também se é possível fazer a mesma coisa com a barra de rolagem

Desde já agradeço.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

scroll=Scrollbar(root)  
scroll.place(x=300,y=90)
listbox = Listbox(root,exportselection=0)
listbox.insert(END, "Selecione")
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
listbox.place(x=50,y=70)

for item in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
listbox.insert(END, item)

scroll2=Scrollbar(root)  
scroll2.place(x=330,y=90)
listbox2 = Listbox(root,exportselection=0)
listbox2.pack()
listbox2.insert(END, "Selecione")
listbox2.config(yscrollcommand=scroll2.set)
listbox2.place(x=175,y=70)

for item in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
  listbox2.insert(END, item)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso aqui:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

scroll=Scrollbar(root)  
scroll.place(x=300,y=90)
listbox = Listbox(root,exportselection=0)
listbox.insert(END, "Selecione")
listbox.config(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
listbox.place(x=50,y=70)

for item in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
  listbox.insert(END, item)

scroll2=Scrollbar(root)  
scroll2.place(x=330,y=90)
listbox2 = Listbox(root,exportselection=0)
listbox2.pack()
listbox2.insert(END, "Selecione")
listbox2.config(yscrollcommand=scroll2.set)
listbox2.place(x=175,y=70)

for item in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
  listbox2.insert(END, item)

# Criei uma função:

def chamada(event):
  global listbox2
  print(event.x)
  print(event.y)
  listbox2.select_set(0)

# E atribui a função ao evento do clique do mouse na
# primeira listbox:

listbox.bind("<Button-1>",chamada)

root.mainloop()
```

Depois é só questão de programação definir onde é a posição do clique e qual você vai marcar na outra lista.